# Уведомление о завершении конкурса приходит раньше завершения конкурса

Tags: дефект, конкурс

Я объявил конкурс и за полчаса **до окончания** конкурса мне пришло уведомление о том, что конкурс **завершён**:

> [image]

На скриншоте есть строка:

> срок окончания конкурса *через 23 минуты*

и уведомление, которое пришло «6 минут назад», с текстом:

> Ваш конкурс ... *завершён*.

Кажется, одно из этих сообщений не является правильным.